# Search for a file or folder from google drive api via the name of the file/folder?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to make a function that can search for a file/folder. If the file/folder exists then it will return the id else will return null from the drive in PHP, but every time I do this it shows that there is some error in q.

```
An error occurred: {
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "message": "Invalid Value",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "q"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid Value"
    }
}
```

The query is:-

```
//testing-folder-of-api is the name of the folder
mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder and name='testing-folder-of-api'
```

I also tried with changing it like:

1. `mimeType!=application/vnd.google-apps.folder` if not a file
2. `name contains 'test.txt'` and `title='test.txt'` for searching it by name.

The solution that I found was that to loop through all the files and check the name individually using a loop which took to much time.

Can someone plz show me how to do it. Please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You should add single quotes around `'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`, as mentioned at [File-specific query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#file_properties):

> **mimeType**: MIME type of the file. Surround with single quotes '.

#### Solution:

```
mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='testing-folder-of-api'
```

Comment: Yes that was what I was doing wrong, Thanks. But how can I also specify in which folder to look at. I tried the '1234567' in parents, but that also gave the error in 'q'. What should I do now.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690625/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-a-specified-folder-using-google-drive-api-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690625/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-a-specified-folder-using-google-drive-api-in-php) I posted a new question. Can you plz explain this in details there.

Comment: Thanks. You really helped a lot. Well I am using Api v2, and also I did post my code in a question that I asked. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690625/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-a-specified-folder-using-google-drive-api-in-php/68723339#68723339](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690625/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-a-specified-folder-using-google-drive-api-in-php/68723339#68723339)