# how to search for a file in a specified folder using google drive api in php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to make a function in PHP that can search files/folder in a specified folder using **Google Drive Api v2** but it always give out the error of invalid value in 'q'.

```
An error occurred: {
    "error": {
         "errors": [{
             "domain": "global",
             "reason": "invalidParameter",
             "message": "Invalid field selection title",
             "locationType": "parameter",
             "location": "fields"
         }],
         "code": 400,
         "message": "Invalid field selection title"
     }
}
```

The value that I passes are:

`Array('q' => "name contains 'test.txt' and title contains 'test.txt' and mimeType='text/plain' and 'parent_folder_id' in parents", 'fields'=> "files(id,name,description,kind,mimeType)")`

I didn't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I recommend switching to V3. and using the google api php client libary

Answer (score 0):

> "name contains 'test.txt' and title contains 'test.txt'

Google drive api v2 does not have a [property](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) called name. it only has title only

> files(id,name,description,kind,mimeType)

Same issue Google drive api v2 does not have a property called name.

Comment: Thanks, Really helped. Well I also posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that you want to retrieve all the files which are named `test` and have the `.txt` extension, then the correct way to make the request is to use the `title` query term.**

Taking this into account, this is how the request will end up looking:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title%20contains%20'test'%20and%20mimeType%20%3D%20'text%2Fplain'
```

A list of supported queries for Drive API v2 is presented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms).

#### Reference

- [Drive API v2 Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you those who have answered to my question.

**This is for Google Api v2**.

Well the solution that I found:

```
/**
 * This function chaecks wether the file given exists or not.
 * @param string $file
 * @param string $mimeType Pass the extention of the file[if a file] or 'folder' if it is a folder. And 'isFile' to set that not a folder.
 * @param string $parent_Id Optional
 * @param string $parent_Name Optional
 * @param string $dataContent Optional
 * @return array|null If the file/folder exists(even inside a dir) it will return the data that corespont to the fields in the $dataContent else will return null 
 */

public function searchContent($file, $mimeType, $parent_Id=null, $parent_Name=null, $dataContent='id,name,description,kind,mimeType'){
    $f = basename($file);
    $fol = "name contains '$f' and name = '$f'";
    if($mimeType!==null){
        if(array_key_exists($mimeType,$this->mime_types)){
            $fol.=' and mimeType=\''.$this->mime_types[$mimeType].'\'';
        } elseif (in_array($mimeType, $this->mime_types)) {
            $fol.=" and mimeType='$mimeType'";
        } elseif ($mimeType == 'isFile') {
            $fol.=' and mimeType!=\''.$this->mime_types['folder'].'\'';
        } else {
            $fol.=" and mimeType='$mimeType'";
        }
    }

    if($parent_Id!==null){
        $fol.= " and parents in '$parent_Id' ";
    } else {
        if($parent_Name!==null){
            $d = $this->searchContent($parent_Name, 'folder', 'root', null, null, 'id');
            if($d!==null){
                $fol.= ' and parents in \''.$d[0]['id'].'\'';
            }
        }
    }
    $d = $this->client->files->listFiles(array('q'=>"$fol", 'fields'=> "files($dataContent)"))['modelData']['files'];
    return (count($d)>0)?$d:null; 
}
```

- `$this->mime_types` is a array that contains mimetypes
  Here is the array:

`$mime_types = array('xls'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel','xlsx'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','xml'=>'text/xml','ods'=>'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet','csv'=>'text/plain','tmpl'=>'text/plain','txt'=>'text/plain','pdf'=>'application/pdf','php'=>'application/x-httpd-php','jpg'=>'image/jpeg','png'=>'image/png','gif'=>'image/gif','bmp'=>'image/bmp','txt'=>'text/plain','doc'=>'application/msword','js'=>'text/js','swf'=>'application/x-shockwave-flash','mp3'=>'audio/mpeg','zip'=>'application/zip','rar'=>'application/rar','tar'=>'application/tar','arj'=>'application/arj','cab'=>'application/cab','html'=>'text/html','htm'=>'text/html','default'=>'application/octet-stream','folder'=>'application/vnd.google-apps.folder','css'=>'text/css');`

This works both for searching files and folder specially for searching inside a folder specific folder.